# How can I get weekly total?

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS and I am having some problems. I have tried several things myself but I keep getting weird results and I don't think I am doing it right.

I have attached a picture of the data. The data shows us birthdays and times.  Provsti is just the place and not relevant. B is dummy variable which is 1 because we have a birth. And then we have year, month, hour, minut and second of the birth. I had to write up a date variable and a date-time variable. I have managed to do this.

Now the problem is that I need to get weekly totals. So how many births occur each week, if we are missing data for a day then that means that a birth did not occur.

My approach was to sum the dummy variable with interval=week. This did not work and I tried to google but could not find a solution.

Best Husky

[DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPBCG.jpg)

Comment: Please read the SAS tag description and provide the information it asks that you provide in your post. An image of your data is absolutely useless.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using SQL, which SAS can process. First, create a computed column for week number:

```
data table;
set table;
week_num = WEEK(date);
run;
```

Then, summarize your table:

```
proc sql;
select week_num
    ,sum(b) as birthCount
from table
group by week_num;
quit;
```

To save the proc sql table to a table, add the statement `create table tableName as` before the `select` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use PROC means and format your date variable with a week format.

```
Proc means data=have;
Class date;
 Format date weeku7.;
VAR analysis_var;
Run;
```

Look at the different week formats to see what meets your needs.